# ArgumentNullException on await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, true);

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-identity, owin, facebook-oauth

I'm using facebook authentication with ASP.NET Identity. I can authenticate with facebook just fine, but when I call `SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync()`, I get an `ArgumentNullException` when it adds claims to the identity. Here's the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType, String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey, String propertyValue) +10798181
   System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value) +34
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +759
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +199
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter.GetResult() +23
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInOrTwoFactor>d__23.MoveNext() +1279
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<ExternalSignInAsync>d__1d.MoveNext() +794
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   SteamAchievements.Web.Controllers.<ExternalLoginCallback>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\projects\facebooksteamachievements\SteamAchievements.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:48
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +84
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

As far as I can tell, I've configured everything correctly. And the best part is, none of the claims have a null type or name. Here's my configuration in StartUp.Auth:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
});
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.FacebookAppId))
{
    var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnAuthenticated = context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },
        AppId = Settings.Default.FacebookAppId,
        AppSecret = Settings.Default.FacebookAppSecret
    };
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
}
```

And here's the ExternalLoginCallback action. It's pretty simple. If the external login succeeded, it creates a user if one does not exist and adds a login if it doesn't exist.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(loginInfo.Login.ProviderKey);
    if (user == null)
    {
        long facebookId = Convert.ToInt64(loginInfo.Login.ProviderKey);
        user = new steam_User {UserName = loginInfo.Login.ProviderKey, FacebookUserId = facebookId};
        var createResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!createResult.Succeeded)
        {
            AddErrors(createResult);
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
    }

    var logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(user.Id);
    if (!logins.Any())
    {
        var addResult = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);
        if (!addResult.Succeeded)
        {
            AddErrors(addResult);
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
    }

    // here's where the exception is thrown
    await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, true);
    return RedirectToLocal("~/");
}
```

It would be great if I could step into `ExternalSignInAsync()`, but I can't. Figuring out how to do that would be a great start.

What am I missing?

If more source code helps, the project is open source and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jrummell/facebooksteamachievements).

Comment: Any reason for the vote to close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Here's a better workaround. I implemented `ClaimsIdentityFactory`, and my implementation doesn't throw `ArgumentNullException`.

```
private class ApplicationIdentityFactory : ClaimsIdentityFactory<steam_User, int>
{
    public async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<steam_User, int> manager, steam_User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        var claims = new[]
                     {
                         new Claim(UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
                         new Claim(UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
                     };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType, UserNameClaimType, RoleClaimType);

        if (manager.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            var roles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
            identity.AddClaims(roles.Select(r => new Claim(RoleClaimType, r)));
        }

        if (manager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            identity.AddClaims(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id));
        }

        return identity;
    }
}
```

---

Here's my workaround. I don't like it, but it works. If ExternalSignInAsync fails, it will fall back on creating an auth cookie with the FormsAuthentication api.

```
try
{
    await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, true);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // For now, here's my work around
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
}
```